# @ConfigurationProperties doesn't update if same values are injected elsewhere without annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configurationproperties

I use @ConfigurationProperties with Zookeeper to update certain property values at runtime.

This relevant part of the code looks like this:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

@Bean("limitedRepository")
public Repository limitedRepository(
        @Qualifier("repository") Repository repository,
        @Value("${some.property-one:1}") int one,
        @Value("${some.property-two:2}") int two) {
    return new LimitedRepository(repository, one, two);
}

@Bean("rateAdjuster")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "some.property")
public RateAdjuster rateAdjuster(
        @Qualifier("limitedRepository") Repository limitedRepository,
        @Value("${some.property-one:1}") int one,
        @Value("${some.property-two:2}") int two,
        @Value("${some.property-three:3}") int three,
        @Value("${some.property-four:4}") int four
        ) {
    return new RateAdjuster(limitedRepository, one, two, three, four);
}
}
```

Bean *limitedRepository* uses values as rates, and *rateAdjuster* is bean with scheduled method that should adjust and set rates to *limitedRepository* bean based on certain criteria.

So my goal here would be:

1. to set all properties on *limitedRepository* and *rateAdjuster* beans when the application runs
2. when I want to update the properties, I want only properties on *rateLimiter* bean to update at runtime (rates on *limitedRepository* should only be updated by *rateAdjuster*).

And it almost works. It sets properties as it should, but something interesting happens.

1. When I try to update properties **three** or **four** (they are set only in *rateAdjuster* bean) via Zookeeper, it works fine, the *rateAdjuster* is updated with those values
2. When I try to update properties **one** or **two** (they are also set in *limitedRepository* bean) via Zookeeper, *rateAdjuster* doesn't update
3. If I put `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "some.property")` on **limitedRepository()** method, then all properties can update at runtime, but this is not what I want

Could anyone help me to understand what is happening here and to hopefully find solution to this problem?

Comment: @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "some.property") will try to apply value on the returned object setters. In your case,RateAdjuster object setters will be called on value change. Do you have valid setters for them ?. Do the properties match on the RateAdjuster ?

Comment: @AbishekramR Actually, that was a problem! Thank you for pointing me in that direction, it didn't have to do anything with what I previously thought was a problem. Spring Boot uses relaxed binding, so properties three and four were similar enough for binding, and the other two weren't.